# Stop comma separation when .replace() method used on content

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code that removes all comments from a  javascript file, however every starting line of the result begins with a comma. This could be because I use `\n` to represent a new line in the replace. This could be the problem, but I do not know any other way to represent a new line in Javascript. Please help!

```js
function fileUploaded() {
  var myUploadedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(myUploadedFile, "UTF-8");
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    var documentNew = evt.target.result.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");
    var str = documentNew;
    var lines = str.split('\n');

    var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
      return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
    });

    filterred = String(filterred).replace(/;/g, "; \n");

    $("#answerDocument1").html(filterred);
  };
};
document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", fileUploaded, false);
$("#doc").keyup(function(evt) {
  var doc = $("#doc").val();
  var documentNew = String(doc).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");
  var str = documentNew;
  var lines = str.split('\n');

  var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
    return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
  });

  filterred = String(filterred).replace(/;/g, "; \n");

  $("#answerDocument2").html(filterred);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Upload A Javascript Document</h3>
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<textarea id="answerDocument1"></textarea>
<br><br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<h3>Paste Code</h3>
<textarea id="doc"></textarea>
<h3>Copy Formatted Code</h3>
<textarea id="answerDocument2" style="resize: none;" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: `.split()` returns an array and `.filter()` returns an array hence `filterred` is also an array. Just do some debugging (like adding a `console.log(String(filterred))`) and you will find the source of the problem.

Comment: @Andreas You mean [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is where you call `String(filterred)` in this part of the code:

```
var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
  return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
});

filterred = String(filterred).replace(/;/g, "; \n");
```

Note that your `filterred` variable is an Array. When you call `String()` on an array, it gives you the array elements joined with commas in between, e.g.

```
String([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
```

will give a result of:

```
"a,b,c"
```

Instead, use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method on the array and explicitly give it an empty string separator:

```
filterred = filterred.join("").replace(/;/g, "; \n");
```

Pay close attention to the suggestion from @Andreas to do some debugging. One thing that can help here is to break apart a chain of calls like the one above into individual statements:

```
filterred = String(filterred);
filterred = filterred.replace(/;/g, "; \n");
```

Now you can put a `debugger;` statement or two, run with the developer tools open, and it will stop in the debugger so you can look at your variables:

```
debugger;
filterred = String(filterred);
debugger;  // Here you will notice that 'filterred' has the commas in it
filterred = filterred.replace(/;/g, "; \n");
```

`console.log();` can be a fine way to debug too, but `debugger;` lets you interact with your code and data more.

Also you have a space after the semicolon in that last line. Make it `";\n"` instead to avoid trailing spaces.

And BTW "filtered" has only one "r" in it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the full working code!

```js
function fileUploaded() {
  var myUploadedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(myUploadedFile, "UTF-8");
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    var documentNew = evt.target.result.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");
    var str = documentNew;
    var lines = str.split('\n');

    var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
      return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
    });

    
    filterred = filterred.join("").replace(/;/g, "; \n");
    $("#answerDocument1").html(filterred);
  };
};
document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", fileUploaded, false);
$("#doc").keyup(function(evt) {
  var doc = $("#doc").val();
  var documentNew = String(doc).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n");
  var str = documentNew;
  var lines = str.split('\n');

  var filterred = lines.filter(function(line) {
    return line.indexOf('//') != 0;
  });

  filterred = filterred.join("").replace(/;/g, "; \n");
  $("#answerDocument2").html(filterred);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Upload A Javascript Document</h3>
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<textarea id="answerDocument1"></textarea>
<br><br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<h3>Paste Code</h3>
<textarea id="doc"></textarea>
<h3>Copy Formatted Code</h3>
<textarea id="answerDocument2" style="resize: none;" readonly></textarea>
```